# Minimum number of moves to light all vertices of a tournament.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, directed-graphs

In every vertex of an oriented complete graph (tournament) $G = \langle V, E\rangle$ there is a light bulb. Initally, all of them are turned off. What is the minimum number of moves required to turn on every light bulb? In one move I can choose any vertex $u$ and turn on the light bulb in $u$ and in every neighbour of $u$. I have no idea other than checking all possibilites.

Comment: There is a king in the tournament.

Comment: If it's a complete graph, isn't one move sufficient?

Comment: No, it's a _directed_ complete graph.

Comment: I see.. i just went to wikipedia and saw "A complete digraph is a directed graph in which every pair of distinct vertices is connected by a pair of unique edges (one in each direction)." but I understand what he means now

Comment: Is it clear what "neighbour" means? Aren't there terms like "out-neighbour" and "in-neighbour" for directed graphs?

Comment: @muzzlator There's a difference between "complete directed graph" and "directed complete graph", but I can't recall that I've ever seen the latter term. Instead, I've seen a tournament called an "**oriented** complete graph". An oriented graph is what you get when you take an undirected graph and replace each undirected edge with a directed edge in **one** direction.

Comment: I think the question almost certainly ought to say "turn on the light-bulb in $u$ and in every *out-neighbor* of $u$" (or, equivalently, every *in-neighbor* of $u$, as long as we're consistent), in which case it is equivalent to Schütte's tournament problem, but agree that it is currently unclear.

Comment: How is it equvialent to Schütte's tournament problem? I can't see it. Also I think the author of the question by "neighbour" means a vertex $v$ such that there is a dierected edge from $u$ to $v$ (so pointing from $u$ to $v$).

Comment: You are asking for the *domination number* $\gamma$ of the tournament $T=(V,E).$ See [K. B. Reid, A. A. MacRae, S. M. Hedetniemi, and S. T. Hedetniemi, "Domination and irredundance in tournaments", Australasian Journal of Combinatorics 29 (2004), 157–172](https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/29/ajc_v29_p157.pdf).

Comment: @MishaLavrov What is "Schütte's tournament problem"? Didn't Schütte have more than one tournament problem?

Comment: @bof I'm thinking of the one [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3612854), which is essentially equivalent to finding the maximum possible domination number of an $n$-vertex tournament.